# Docker. Как устроен флоу деплоя фронтенда?

Tags: docker

Не могу понять как деплоить фронтенд без лишних файлов. Нужно что бы в прод попадали только билд файлы. Но при этом должна быть возможность тестировать. Например на circleCI. Подскажите кто нибудь. Или может ссылки на хорошие стати по этой теме есть или книги.

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Есть репозиторий. AngularJS например. На тест мне нужен весь проект. С тестами и всеми файлами. На прод же должен попасть только собраный бандл. Я не вижу в докере возможности это реализовать

Comment: Системные тесты выполняются вне приложения (снаружи), для модульных приложение не обязательно собирать, я все равно не понимаю проблемы. Если на прод что-то не должно попасть - ну, не закидывайте это в образ и всё.

Comment: Без деталей: опишите в сборке разные профили для разных окружений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример билда ангуляра для прода:

```
FROM node:8.7.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /ng-app
WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY package.json* /ng-app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /ng-app/
RUN "$(npm bin)/ng" build --prod --env=prod

FROM nginx:1.13.5-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY --from=0 /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Да так и сделал.  Multi-stage builds называется. Теперь интересно насколько медленее будет проходить запрос от прокси nginx. Теперь ведь в 2 раза больше запросов. Или это незаметно будет?

Comment: Да 2x запросов, но это типичная конфигурация для бекендов - server upstream и proxy. Тут также nginx upstream -> nginx or traefik, etc. В локальной сети (в пределах одного сервера) накладные расходы минимальны.